# Output an image barcode with HTML code

Tags: html, angularjs, barcode

I am new at angular application development, and I am looking for a solution that will generate a barcode with simple HTML code. Was messing around with [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146336/Creating-a-Code-Barcode-using-HTML-CSS-and-Java) , however, am looking for a solution that will generate an image output.

Comment: nothing was wrong with the link i've posted, just that it does not produce an image output, but draws the barcode in html code.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the link below:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146336/Creating-a-Code-Barcode-using-HTML-CSS-and-Java

This solution could work for you :).

Comment: Thanks :) that'a the link i've posted too... it does not produce an image